# Simple Linq Dynamic Query question

Tags: linq, dynamicquery

In Linq [Dynamic Query](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), Scott Guthrie shows an example Linq query:

```
var query =
    db.Customers.
    Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
    OrderBy("CompanyName").
    Select("new( CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

Notice the projection `new( CompanyName as Name, Phone)`.  If I have a class like this:

```
public class CompanyContact {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```

How could I essentially "cast" his result using the CompanyContact data type without doing a foreach on each record and dumping it in to a different data structure?  To my knowledge the only .Select available is the Dymanic Query version which only takes a string and parameter list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A far as I can see from the article you cite, The dynamic query methods return IQueryable<> objects, which mean the normal Select() should be available.

```
var query = 
    db.Customers. 
    Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10). 
    OrderBy("CompanyName"). 
    Select( c => new CompanyContact {Name = c.CompanyName, c.Phone});
```

You may have to explicitly give the type for the Select

```
    Select<Customer>( c => new CompanyContact {Name = c.CompanyName, c.Phone});
```

Comment: I may have to wrap the entire query minus the Select in a cast just to get the lambda enabled Select method.

Comment: The only thing the cast should do is enable the IntelliSense.  If the object isn't that type before hand, casting won't be able to chagne it.